# Page view mode and node settings

Tags: nodes

I have been creating new view modes with the entity view mode module as well as created template files for the new view modes.

At this point I would like to know how I tell a given page or url (ie. front page) which view mode of a particular content type to use

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/118133/page-view-mode-and-node-settings#

Answer (score 0):

You can create a view and go to **Format** section and display it as **content** then select the **view mode** you want. After that go to  `admin/config/system/site-information` and change the **Default front page** to the view that you have created.